# Accessing files between projects Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, directory

I have a question regarding projects in Eclipse. I have in my workspace a few projects, among which I have let's say projects A and B. Now, from project A, I need to access a folder that is located in project B. Could you give me a hint on how to do this?

**EDIT :** I would like to do this without adding project B to Java Build Path

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on project in project explorer. Go to JAvaBuild Path->Projects->Select project to add

Update:
In that case, your are left with only 2 options create jar of project B or manually copy content of project B to project A

Comment: I omitted to say in my question. I would like to do that without adding the project to the build path.

Answer (score 0):

```
Right click on project A
Properties > Java Build Path > Source > Link Source
Browse to B's source folder.
Finish.
```